# How to move only files in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, file-management, find, mv

How can I move only the plain files (not the directories) from one folder in Linux to another folder using the `mv` command?

I have tried `mv * ~/`, but it copied everything including the directories.

Comment: your comments mention an additional restriction: the command shouldn't move hidden files from the current working directory.  if this is correct, could you please edit your question to mention this?  saying "move only files" makes us think "move all the files", which includes hidden files.

Comment: Do the files have a certain extension? If so you can use `mv *.ext ~/.`

Answer (score 36):

You can try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} destination_path \;
```

Comment: Wow, someone who knows how to use find.  For completeness you should use -name [^.]\* in the find, ie ---   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name [^.]\* -exec mv {} path \;

Comment: DO NOT COPY-PASTE THIS INTO YOUR SHELL. The semicolon will cause it to execute immediately. :)

Comment: @SherwoodCallaway  The semicolon is to mark the end of `-exec`

Answer (score 6):

@Mereghost is very close. Here's what I get to move all files (including hidden files), but not directories:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -exec mv -n {} /destination_path \;
```

The `.` after find assumes you current directory is the source of the files you want to move. If not, the command can be revised, as follows:

```
find /source_path -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -exec mv -n {} /dest_path \;
```

If you want to move only regular files and not hidden files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[!.]*' -exec mv -n {} /dest_path \;
```

If you want to move only hidden files and not regular files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -exec mv -n {} /dest_path \;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a "use a hammer for everything" kinda guy so I use bourne shell programs for stuff others use external programs for...

```
for file in * .* 
do
  test -f "$file" && mv "$file" "$HOME"/
done
```

Some people like to get things done in as little typing as possible but I'm a pretty quick typist and I've got stuff like this built into my brain so it's not too much of a pain to do this instead of looking up the exact arguments to find and exec and all that.

YMMV, though...

Comment: thanks for that i will try it.
but i still need the other answer because its for a project i am doing in linux course.

thanks alot

Comment: This *is* an answer to your question.  mv has no understanding of files or directories or fifos or other special files.  mv only understands directory entries and inodes, and as far as it is concerned, those are all the same regardless of file type.  To allow mv to only move a specific type of file, you need something like test or find that can actually look at the inode to see what the file is.  In other words, you're being asked a trick question if you are being asked to do it *only* with mv.

Comment: And I say that mv understands inodes *only* because it is able to move a file from one filesystem to another, which is technically a cp then an rm, not an mv (which is really just a ln then rm).  Look hardlinks and directory entries.

Comment: shorty: This is a good answer, you have to using something besides the mv command (at least the shell).  This is about a basic as it gets without programming.

Answer (score 1):

For many use cases with all your files having a ".extension" and your folders without an extension, you can try:

```
mv source_directory/*.* target_directory/
```

I am sure this is not a robust solution and am keen to update it to be one, but appears simple and quick for many use cases. Note this will move hidden files with an extension, and ignore those without extensions.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score 0):

This may be considered bad practice/dangerous, in which case please comment! But how about

```
cp * ~; rm *
```

Because the default behaviours of both `cp` and `rm` are to ignore directories, it should have the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

If you have no folders with name with dot in it you can move all of them simply:

mv *.* ~/destinationfolder

(My assumption is all your files are something.something (in my case all are usually))

BUT thanks to other answers - very helpfull. THX

Answer (score -3):

mv `find ./sourcedir/* -type f` ./destdir

Comment: This will fail for any files that contain whitespace in their name. The output of commands that print filenames should never be parsed unless it can be guaranteed it is properly delimited. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for the main idea. Using `find`'s `-exec` option is the best way to avoid the problem.